# Sim Registration Script for access to Internet

Tags: beginner, python-3.x

**Details:** Based on the input parameter to return corresponding output which is needed for setting & accessing Internet over interface [ppp0]. If the SIM is registered[ status = 1].
This script will be called in another based on cli.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import datetime
import sys, time, logging, codecs
from gsmmodem.modem import GsmModem
from gsmmodem.exceptions import InterruptedException, CommandError
from gsmmodem import serial_comms

'''
Modem Basic Configuration Settings.
Baud rate can be 115200 or 460800. Use 460800
'''
PORT="/dev/ttyACM3"
BAUDRATE=460800
PIN=None

#Setting up the Modem and misc stuff.
modem = GsmModem(PORT, BAUDRATE)
modem.connect(PIN)

#Uncomment below line to get debug trace info.
#logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)

'''
Under below sim registration script we have 3 main things.
1. To fetch the signal strength
2. To fetch to which operator the sim has been connected to
3. To fetch the status which becomes the determining factor under the other network-monitoring script
'''
try:

        if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
            if str(sys.argv[1]) == 'Signal_Strength':
                signal_strength=modem.signalStrength
                time.sleep(3)
                print(int(signal_strength))

            elif str(sys.argv[1]) == 'Operator':
                operator_name=modem.networkName
                time.sleep(3)
                print(str(operator_name))

            else:
                print("No Arguments")

        else:
            cregResult=modem.write('AT+CREG?',timeout=10)
            if "+CREG: 0,1" not in cregResult and "+CREG: 0,5" not in cregResult:
                if "+CREG: " in cregResult:
                    print("-1")
                else:
                    print(0)
            else:
                print(1)

        modem.close()

except Exception as ex:
    print(str(ex))
    print("Error in Connection")
    modem.close()
```

**Expected & Observed Output:**

```
root@[Device_Name]:~# python3 test.py Signal_Strength
22

root@[Device_Name]:~# python3 test.py Operator 
Play

root@[Device_Name]:~# python3 test.py 
1
```

**Problem 1:** To cover corner scenarios as to where this would fail and further improve this code.

**Trial 1:**
For this I have included the following fix in the code when AT+CREG? returns blank output. Is there a better way to work around this?

```
    cregResult=modem.write('AT+CREG?',timeout=10)
    if "+CREG: 0,1" not in cregResult and "+CREG: 0,5" not in cregResult:
        if "+CREG: " in cregResult:
            print("-1")
        else:
            print(0)
    else:
        print(1)

modem.close()
```

**Miscellaneous Details:**

HE910D Telit Hardware/Modem

Python3 Version : 3.5.3

Modem Version : 12.0.0.28

[Telit HE910 DataSheet](https://www.telit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Telit_HE910_Product_Description_r11.pdf)

Could not add tags gsm-modem/serial/AT-commands as I do not have enough rep. : /

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. This site requires that submitted code [works as intended](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or is bug-free to the best of your knowledge. In its present form I'm afraid your code is not yet eligible here.

Comment: I see. I have made the changes. Is this acceptable? Code works as intended, just need improvements on this.